# Universal and Existential Quantifiers - Variables as Natural Numbers

Tags: quantifiers

It is said that an proposition with a universal quantifier represents a possibly infinite conjunction, and a proposition with an existential quantifier a possibly infinite disjunction. How can one illustrate this approach, where the quantified variables can take as values the natural numbers?

Comment: Can you think of a predicate on the natural numbers that is satisfied by infinitely many of them?  Can you think of a predicate on the natural numbers that is satisfied by at least one of them?  Having concrete example predicates in mind may help you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the language has the *numerals*, i.e. the terms corresponding to the natural numbers, we can write e.g. $\forall x (x \ge 0)$ as :

> $(0 \ge 0) \land (1 \ge 0) \land (2 \ge 0) \land \ldots$

The same for e.g. $\exists x (x=0)$ :

> $(0=0) \lor (1=0) \lor (2=0) \lor \ldots$